# Encountering error 1045 while connecting php file to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I have been trying to connect my PHP file to MySQL database for a while, now I'm using WAMP server and encountering error 1045, I have also setup a password and tried various settings given on net.

[this is the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyDN6.png)

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "password", "registration");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

here is the code I'm running, registration is the database,I have created it using phpmyadmin

Comment: the details used here to connect are the same as those stored for the `mysqladmin` config?

Comment: Already checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "registration");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: you can remove password